# DXA+ JAVA: Managing specific errors (404,500)

Tags: dxa, java

When there's a error in the app, like 404 or 500 error, we would like to know if there's a standard using DXA to manage this kind of errors in 2 different pages. Currently, we are seeing that by default dxa goes always to a generic error page /error.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC DXA has a Tridion managed page for 404 errors, which you can add whatever content you like to, but 500 errors show a non-Tridion managed error page (as with 500 errors there is no guarantee that Tridion Content Delivery is even available to load a page).